# how to verify signature in HMAC using by LUA

Tags: java, lua, jwt, token, kong

I just started programming in LUA scripting language and I want to convert java token authentication to Lua and use it in Kong API gateway. I started to convert but the question is what is the best practice for HMAC or SHA256 signature verification? How can i use it in Kong API Gateway? I can't find an appropriate lib for this conversion. When I found HMAC for this solution I cant add it to LUA, maybe it isn't the best way or I cant!

Comment: it seems to be unusual that how much I search it on the internet I can't find the answer or I found with no reputation, maybe nobody like that or nobody doesn't use LUA verification signature in Kong API Gateway! :)

Comment: you can use the kong-oidc plugin to do this

Comment: @HansZ. does it verify the signature?